# mongodb $last and $first issue

Tags: mongodb

```
db.getCollection('sometable').aggregate([{
{$group:{
    _id:null,
    firstRecord:{$first:'$timeStamp'},
    lastRecord:{$last:'$timeStamp'}
    }}
}])
```

The order of fetching the record in two difference database if different

first Database

```
firstRecord:22-09-2023,
lastRecord:23-09-2023
```

second Database

```
firstRecord:23-09-2023,
lastRecord:22-09-2023
```

data is same in both database

is there any database setting related to this..?

Comment: I don't think `"$group"` is a valid operator for `find`.  Are you actually using `aggregate`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs
I am doing a aggregate only

Comment: The data in the separate databases may have all the same documents, but the document ordering within each database may be different.  `"$first"`/`"$last"` will return objects from the first/last document in the database.  Perhaps you want to `"$sort"` before `"$group"`?  However, the date format appears not to be using BSON Date objects, nor ISO8601 string format, so sorting, etc., will be problematic.

Comment: @rickhg12hs
I understand sorting is an option, but I want to know why it is different?

Comment: Because the two databases have different document ordering.  I.e., database 1 may have `"_id": 1`, `"_id": 2`, `"_id": 3`, and database 2 may have `"_id": 1`, `"_id": 3`, `"_id": 2`.

Comment: From [$first](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/): "_Returns the result of an expression for the first document in a group of documents. **Only meaningful when documents are in a defined order**_."

Comment: You can use `$min`and `$max` instead of `$first` and `$last`. Or you may also use a `$sort` before the `$group` to force the same order on the databases